# How to prevent object from sliding when moving platform diagonally in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I am trying to implement a simple fork lift truck in Unity. Moving left, right, up and down is working fine:
[Box stays in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lct5e.jpg)

Moving left/right and up/down at the same time (box moving diagonally) the box is sliding off the forks:
[Box is sliding off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aTPr.jpg)

Does anyone have an idea?

What i already tried to do:

- When picking up the box, make it a child of the fork lift truck
- Adding Physics Material 2D with high friction to forks and box
- Set the x-velocity of the box to the x-velocity of the fork lift truck
- Decreasing Movement- and Lifting speed of the fork lift truck
- Decreasing fixed timestemp in Project Settings
- Increasing Mass and Gravity Scale of the Box

Fork lift truck and the box both have a rigidbody2D attached with Body Type Dynamic and Collision Detection Continuous.

Currently iam moving the fork lift truck with the following code:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Moving Left/Right
        if (moveRight)
        {
            timeElapsedDeceleration = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, drivingSpeed, timeElapsedAcceleration / 2), rb.velocity.y);
            timeElapsedAcceleration += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else if (moveLeft)
        {
            timeElapsedDeceleration = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, -drivingSpeed, timeElapsedAcceleration / 2), rb.velocity.y);
            timeElapsedAcceleration += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            timeElapsedAcceleration = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, timeElapsedDeceleration / 2), rb.velocity.y);
            timeElapsedDeceleration += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }

        //Lifting
        if (moveForksUp && forks.transform.localPosition.y <= maxLiftHeight)
        {
            forks.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(forks.transform.localPosition.x, forks.transform.localPosition.y + liftingSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            liftableMast.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(liftableMast.transform.localPosition.x, liftableMast.transform.localPosition.y + liftingSpeed / 1.5f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else if (moveForksDown && forks.transform.localPosition.y >= minLiftHeight)
        {
            forks.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(forks.transform.localPosition.x, forks.transform.localPosition.y - liftingSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            liftableMast.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(liftableMast.transform.localPosition.x, liftableMast.transform.localPosition.y - liftingSpeed / 1.5f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }
```

The box should not slide off when moving e.g. left and up and the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution how it works.
I am moving the forks up and down with physics now.

1. Add a Rigidbody2D to the Forks, set Type to "Dynamic", use very high mass like 100000 and set gravity scale to 0 so it won't be affected by the box with a mass of 2
2. If you pick up the box set it to a child of the forks.
3. If the box falls off the forks unchild it again

Moving Left/Right is the same.
For Moving Up/Down use the following code:

```
//Forks Up/Down
    if (moveUp)
    {
        rbForks.velocity = new Vector2(0, 100 * Time.deltaTime * liftingSpeed);

    }
    else if (moveDown)
    {
        rbForks.velocity = new Vector2(0, -100 * Time.deltaTime * liftingSpeed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when moving try to parent the box to the forklift's front thing and disable the rigidbody, something like this

```
if (isMoving)
      {
          box.trasform.parent = Lifter; 
          box.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
      }
      else 
      {
          box.trasform.parent = null; 
          box.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
      }
```

Comment: That would be a possibility but the physics should always be activated. The reason for this is that I am making a physics-based game where the box should also be able to fall off on, for example, steep slopes or jerky driving. Especially when several boxes are on top of each other this is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a fixed Joint 2D component to the box and connect it to the player whenever you want.

If it doesn't work, add two fixed joints

Comment: I tried it but when i attach the player rb to the fixed joint 2D of the box it will only work for the x-direction. The truck has always the same y-value. The object for lifting doesn't have a rigidbody which i can attach to the fixed joint 2D of the box.

Comment: Can you use rigidbody with kinematic mode for lifting object?

Comment: Also, instead of connecting the joint to the player, try connecting it to the fork

Comment: If it still doesn't work, run all these steps together with childing the box to the fork